# Knowing the sums $\sum {a_i}^k$ is equivalent to knowing $a_i $ individually.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, representation-theory

This is an embarrassing question since it looks like a basic mathematics problem. But I struggled for hours to prove this and I could not get a single hint about it.
This statement is given in the textbook 'Representation Theory - W. Fulton', which is originally written in this way: knowing the sums $\sum {\lambda_i}^k$ of the kth powers of the eigenvalues of a given element
$g \in G$ is equivalent to knowing the eigenvalues $\{\lambda_i\}$ of $g$ themselves.
I wrote down in $a_i$ since I think eigenvalues are not the point of the statement.
Can you give me a hint to prove this?

Comment: This seems to be a context based thing. For example, if your eigenvalues are {-1, 1}, and you set $k=2$, you can't determine the eigenvalues from the sum. The author I think is saying that for their specific problem, you don't need to know more information. But we here would need more info to help ya out :)

Comment: If you know all the sums of powers then you know all the elementary symmetric polynomials (Newton's identities), and therefore you can write a polynomial of which your numbers are roots.

Comment: I think you misunderstood, $k$ need not be fixed and assuming that we know all the information about sums $\sum {a_i}^k$ for all natural number $k$ and for real numbers $a_i$.

Comment: Oh I never heard about Newton's identities. Thanks I'll check for it.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek You should post that as an answer.